# Exception EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, glassfish, eclipselink

I try to deploy service that retrieves data from table and diplay it over https using REST Jersey with Glassfish What I did is i configured the https and it works also I tested a jpa it can retrieves data from table, but the problem is when i merge between the jpa treatment and service Jersey, it throws exceptions below, so if anyone has a solution please tell me what ca do to solve this problem thanks:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

root cause

Exception [EclipseLink-30005] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.PersistenceUnitLoadingException Exception Description: An exception was thrown while searching for persistence archives with ClassLoader: WebappClassLoader (delegate=true; repositories=WEB-INF/classes/) Internal Exception: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [] failed. Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-7305] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException Exception Description: An exception was thrown while processing the mapping file from URL: [file:glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps//WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/orm.xml], error using JPA 1.0 orm.xsd was [Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.IntegrityException
Descriptor Exceptions:

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setCascade], [getCascade] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeObjectMapping[m_cascade] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setDiscriminatorColumn], [getDiscriminatorColumn] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeObjectMapping[m_discriminatorColumn] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setDiscriminatorClasses], [getDiscriminatorClasses] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[m_discriminatorClasses] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setJoinColumns], [getJoinColumns] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[m_joinColumns] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setPrivateOwned], [getPrivateOwned] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_privateOwned-->orm:private-owned/text()] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VariableOneToOneAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setSelectedColumns], [getSelectedColumns] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.locking.OptimisticLockingMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[m_selectedColumns] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.locking.OptimisticLockingMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setType], [getType] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.locking.OptimisticLockingMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_type-->@type] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.locking.OptimisticLockingMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setName], [getName] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.columns.PrimaryKeyJoinColumnMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_name-->@name] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.columns.PrimaryKeyJoinColumnMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setName], [getName] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.TransientAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_name-->@name] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.TransientAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setHints], [getHints] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedStoredProcedureQueryMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[m_hints] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedStoredProcedureQueryMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setParameters], [getParameters] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedStoredProcedureQueryMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[m_parameters] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedStoredProcedureQueryMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setName], [getName] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedStoredProcedureQueryMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_name-->@name] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedStoredProcedureQueryMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setColumn], [getColumn] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VersionAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeObjectMapping[m_column] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VersionAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setTemporal], [getTemporal] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VersionAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeObjectMapping[m_temporal] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VersionAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setConvert], [getConvert] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VersionAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_convert-->orm:convert/text()] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.VersionAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-86] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The instance variable [m_validation] in the class [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.PrimaryKeyMetadata] is not accessible. Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_validation-->@validation] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.PrimaryKeyMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setOrderBy], [getOrderBy] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToManyAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_orderBy-->orm:order-by/text()] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.ManyToManyAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setQuery], [getQuery] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_query-->orm:query/text()] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.queries.NamedQueryMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setGetMethodName], [getGetMethodName] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.mappings.AccessMethodsMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_getMethodName-->@get-method] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.mappings.AccessMethodsMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setName], [getName] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.columns.ColumnMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_name-->@name] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.columns.ColumnMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setName], [getName] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.mappings.MapKeyMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_name-->@name] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.mappings.MapKeyMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setDescription], [getDescription] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EmbeddableAccessor] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_description-->orm:description/text()] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EmbeddableAccessor --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setStrategy], [getStrategy] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.sequencing.GeneratedValueMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_strategy-->@strategy] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.sequencing.GeneratedValueMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setXMLMappingMetadataComplete], [getXMLMappingMetadataComplete] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.xml.XMLPersistenceUnitMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_xmlMappingMetadataComplete-->orm:xml-mapping-metadata-complete/text()] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.xml.XMLPersistenceUnitMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setName], [getName] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.sequencing.SequenceGeneratorMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLDirectMapping[m_name-->@name] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.sequencing.SequenceGeneratorMetadata --> [])

Exception [EclipseLink-87] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException Exception Description: The methods [setUniqueConstraints], [getUniqueConstraints] in the object [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.sequencing.TableGeneratorMetadata] are not accessible Internal Exception: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks) Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.mappings.XMLCompositeCollectionMapping[m_uniqueConstraints] Descriptor: XMLDescriptor(org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.sequencing.TableGeneratorMetadata --> [])

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)

java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission suppressAccessChecks)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because you have security manager enabled in your JVM and have disabled the permission for reflection.  You need to grant this permission to the eclipselink jar, or in general.

EclipseLink does not have this issue in Glassfish, so how are you accessing JPA?  Are you using JPA on a remote client?  The full exception stack would help determine this.